# In Microsoft Access(2016) is it possible to create empty reports without any data?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

In Microsoft Access(2016) is it possible to create reports without any data inserted into the database? If so, Can the reports be "refreshed" after the data has been entered? I am new to ms access!

Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, you can create reports before data has been input. Queries, forms, reports are 'refreshed' every time they are opened. Have you completed an introductory tutorial?

Comment: Yes, although if it's a complex report with any or all of group headers/footers, page headers/footers and sub-reports, it would be difficult to check that the layout and formatting is working as you would expect.